# Integral $ \int x\cos(1+x^2)\sin(1-x^3)\; dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

So I have to solve this integral $$ \int x\cos(1+x^2)\sin(1-x^3)\; dx $$

I know that there are ways to solve trigonometric integrals depending on do the sine and cosine have odd or even degree or if they are represented in some of the standard forms, and if nothing, some of them can be solved using trigonometric identities to simplify the expression to make it easy to integrate. But, in this case I don't have a good idea, I tried to use the formula

$$\sin\alpha\cos\beta= \frac{1}{2}(\sin(\alpha + \beta)+\sin(\alpha-\beta))$$

but it turns out it isn't helpful because, then I have the following integral

$$\frac{1}{2} \int x(\sin(2+x^2-x^3)+\sin(x^2+x^3))\; dx $$

which doesn't seem any less complicated than the one I had at the beginning. Any ideas?

Comment: What makes you think there is an indefinite integral?

Comment: @almagest i am not sure what you mean, are you trying to say that function under integral has no primitive function in the set of elementary functions?

Comment: I am 90% sure that is the case. That is why I asked the question. But if this was an old Putnam problem, for example, then I would maybe have to think again!

Comment: @almagest I have no idea if this was on Putnam or not, but i have the solution to this in my papers, so i thought that it has elementary primitive function, but the problem is that i can't solve it

Comment: If you have the solution, why are you asking here?

Comment: @almagest Seems that you don't understand me, i have the final primitive function, not the whole procedure of solving this.

Comment: Please share your anti-derivative

Comment: @Dr.MV i second this resquest

Comment: @Dr.MV  $\frac{-1}{4}x^2cos2x^2 + \frac{1}{8}sin2x^2 + c$  there you go.

Comment: That isn't the correct antiderivative.  There is no cubic term to be found.

Comment: @Dr.MV Oh, does that means that there's no antiderivative of this function in elementary functions or it means that there is, but this is not the one, and if there is, do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @cdummie, I'm pretty sure the $\sin$ argument is supposed to be quadratic, then the integral is easy to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will make an educated guess that this integral is supposed to be:

> $$\int x\cos(1+x^2)\sin(1-x^2)\; dx$$

Then, by using the OP's suggestion, we tranform the product into a sum:

$$\frac{1}{2} \int x \sin 2 ~dx-\frac{1}{2} \int x \sin (2x^2)dx=\frac{\sin 2}{4}x^2+\frac{1}{8} \cos (2x^2)+C$$

---

The 'antiderivative' the OP provided in the comments leads to the integral:

$$\frac{-1}{4}x^2 \cos2x^2 + \frac{1}{8} \sin2x^2 + C=\int x^3 \sin (2x^2) dx$$

This is obviously not the same integral.

---

The first integral can be easily generalized to an arbitrary degree:

$$\int x^{n-1} \cos(1+x^n)\sin(1-x^n)\; dx=$$

$$=\frac{1}{2} \int x^{n-1} \sin 2 ~dx-\frac{1}{2} \int x^{n-1} \sin (2x^n)dx=\frac{\sin 2}{2n}x^n+\frac{1}{4n} \cos (2x^n)+C$$

Comment: What if it is $x^3$ instead of $x^2$? Is it proven that it cannot be solve? @Yuriy S

Comment: @TonyMa, it's very likely that a closed form antiderivative in terms of elementary functions doesn't exist in this case. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm for further reference